# hide url directory

Tags: url

I have a website:

```
www.mydomain.com/subfolder/subfolder/index.php
```

How could always hide the directory names from the url. I mean always hide the 2 subfolders' names from the url as the page changes.
Example:
These urls:

```
www.mydomain.com/subfolder/subfolder/index.php
www.mydomain.com/subfolder/subfolder/about.php
www.mydomain.com/subfolder/subfolder/contact.php
...
```

Becomes:

```
www.mydomain.com/index
www.mydomain.com/about
www.mydomain.com/contact
...
```

I want to use the last mentioned urls for requesting these pages, too, without typing a horrible long url.

Comment: Hi there, are the subfolders known in advance or are they dynamic? Probably you can do this with Apache's mod_rewrite but I need more info

Answer (score 1):

you can find some good hints when you will look for mod_rewrite or mod rewrite in htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Rewrite engine, you can use a simple rewriting pattern similar to this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /subfolder/subfolder/$1.php
```