# showing contents of another page without changing url

Tags: php

I already have pages like

```
http://example.com/page1
http://example.com/page2
http://example.com/page3
```

I need to load those pages on following subdomain

```
http://page1.example.com/
http://page2.example.com/
http://page3.example.com/
```

It should work as http://page1.example.com/ should load contents of http://example.com/page1, **without changing URL in browser address bar**

I have used following code, but it changes URL in browser address bar

```
header('Location: http://example.com/page1');
```

Help please.

Comment: .htaccess mod rewrite. Here: http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896810/hide-url-directory/13896864#13896864

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is kind of a hack:

```
// Just add the below few lines of code in your subdomain page - http://page1.example.com/
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('http://example.com/page1');
echo $content;
?>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: if he doesn't have access to .htaccess or don't have mod_rewrite, this is kind of solution. But if he has access to .htaccess and has mod_rewrite, this is not good solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'http://example.com/page1';
?>
```

This imports all contents of the page. You can also use "include_once" instead of "include" if there is a session_start() being called more than once.

Similarly,

```
<?php
require 'http://example.com/page1';
?>
```

"require" stops loading the rest of the page if the file is not found, whereas "include" does not stop.